# give every user role for every page on laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

im working on a laravel 5.5 project 
and they told me to make role for every page 
create edit update delete search softdelete

so i have created user table 
this is the migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_name',40)->unique();
        $table->string('user_email',40)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('user_phone',40)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->integer('user_department');
        $table->string('password',60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

and i have created model table this is the migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('model_name',40)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

and i have created modelroles table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('modelroles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('model_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('create');
        $table->integer('read');
        $table->integer('update');
        $table->integer('softdelete');
        $table->integer('delete');
        $table->integer('restore');
        $table->integer('search');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and i have created middlewaer called roleMiddleware 
this is the code

```
use Closure;
class roleMiddleware
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

so how can i connect them together in the middleware 
what i want is to give every user role in every page create read update delete ect 
mean check the url the request come from 
and check the user id 
and check the model id
and check the user_id and the model_id inside modelroles 
and if he can create edit update delete on the model 
i dont want to use packages like this 
https://github.com/laravel-enso/RoleManager
or this 
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
i dont want to connect users with global role 
i want to give every user role for every controller

Comment: I would suggest you to use https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust this package.

Comment: Have you tried Polices and Gates?

Comment: @AnarBayramov that package is outdated, last update was on April 11 :(

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission you can use this one